# Avatars from different size images

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to display round avatars from uploaded images.
If users upload squared images(width equals to height), then there is no problem.

If I could know width is longer than height or shorter, I could solve the problem.

But actually, I don't know it and the problem I couldn't use jquery.

I am using react.js and the current status is like this;

I made a code when the width is longer because the width is longer often than height.

[Avatar which is cut left and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1vR3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches to this. The simplest would be to do this via CSS by expanding the image to the element's bound while maintaining its aspect ratio.

OR

You can restrict the user to upload only an image of a particular dimension using frontend validations or process an image as per your liking via API services like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations) and then use it.

**Using CSS**

```css
img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit:cover; /*this property does the magic*/
  border-radius:50%;
}

.avatar{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://www.milesanthonysmith.com/uploads/1/4/0/0/14006904/anchor-beard-style-1_orig.png") center center;
  background-size:cover; /*this property does the magic*/
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<!--using in a image element-->
<img src="https://www.milesanthonysmith.com/uploads/1/4/0/0/14006904/anchor-beard-style-1_orig.png" alt="">

<!--using in a div-->
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in pure JavaScript by simply checking the height and the width of the image. Simple example:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("profile-picture");
if(img.height === img.width){
  console.log("Height and width are equal");
} else if (img.height > img.width) {
  console.log("Height is greater than width");
} else {
  console.log("Width is greater than height");
}
```

```html
<img id="profile-picture" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-picture-of-smiling-handsome-businessman-in-office-265383200.jpg" />
```